# Phonegap Build Camera not working

Tags: ios, cordova, camera, phonegap-build

I'm currently building my first Phonegap/Cordova app and there are a few things that I cannot get to work. To save time I decided to use Adobe`s Build Service (Version 3.3.0 - also tried 3.5.0).

***1. Camera***
I tried several ways but nothing seemed to work. I want the app to open the camera. This should launch it and save the result in a base64 code:

**JS**

```
    function capturePhoto(){
    navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto,null,{sourceType:1,quality:60});
}

function uploadPhoto(data){
// this is where you would send the image file to server

    cameraPic.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + data;
    // Successful upload to the server
    navigator.notification.alert(
        'Your Photo has been uploaded',  // message
        okay,                           // callback
        'Photo Uploaded',              // title
        'OK'                          // buttonName
    );

    // upload has failed Fail

    /* 

    if (failedToUpload){

    navigator.notification.alert(
        'Your Photo has failed to upload',
        failedDismissed,
        'Photo Not Uploaded',
        'OK'
        );

    } 
    */


}

function okay(){
    // Do something
}
```

**BUTTON**

```
<a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" onclick="capturePhoto();">Photo</a>
```

***2. Offline***

When the App discovers that the device is offline the user should get redirected.
This is what I have:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);
    function onOffline()
    {
    window.location = "noi.html";
    }
}
```

I also tried to put the onOffline function outside the onDeviceReady () function...

I`m looking forward to get your help.

Thanks,
Max

Comment: Have you added plugins in condig.xml?

Comment: I think so... This is my config.xml [link](http://pastebin.com/LvYW44YK)

Comment: Maybe try to remove the feature lines. Not sure if they can hurt but at least they're useless.

Comment: Have the same problems. Did you manage to solve it.

Comment: Maybe this answer helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35315002/279712

Answer (score 0):

@Don, this is pretty old. so I doubt you still have this problem, but others.

**On #1**, your did not use `destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL`, which should have been in your options. You used *sourceType*, which gets you the camera. The documentation is unclear on this. It implies that it will return a base64, but this is not so.

**On #2**, you need to use the plugin [networkInformation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information/), which you did not mention or use in the code posted. -- Jesse