# Using camera on Phonegap app with only HTML input, without Camera API

Tags: android, ios, cordova, camera, phonegap-build

Is it possible to get a photo from camera in a phonegap app only with HTML input, without Camera API?

**Scenario**

I developed an app and encapsulated it through Phonegap *(Build)*

Users can submit photos using html file input. But there is no option to take a new photo from camera, only gallery and files (and any other storage app like drive or dropbox, if it is the case).

I would like to enable the camera option, but without the PhoneGap's Camera API.

**Solutions**

I've tried the following solutions without success:

---

**1. The "capture" attribute (from [Raymond Camden post](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2013/05/20/capturing-camerapicture-data-without-phonegap/))**

With this method, all you have to do is to add the "capture" attribute like this:

```
<input type="file" capture="camera" accept="image/*" id="JustChooseAnID">
```

Raymond explains that with this method you don't need to use PhoneGap's Camera API since Google developed this option and showed it in a [Google IO presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EPYnGFEcis4&feature=youtube_gdata_player) and, according to Google devs and also Raymond, it works.

But.. not for me.

---

**2. Config Phonegap to ask camera's permission (from [Jorge Lizaso's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29926539/using-camera-on-phonegap-build))**

"Maybe the camera option is not showed up because your app doesn't have the proper permissions"

In the above question, 4 methods are mentioned to indirectly ask and receive the proper permissions to use the camera.

I have already tried methods 2 and 4 and, although my app now asks for camera permission and I allowed it properly, when I use the file input, all the options are presented (like gallery and files), but no camera.

---

**3 (and 1). Use the latest version of webkit with [Crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/) to ensure solution #1**

With the possibility of my android webview be outdated (and not compatible with solution #1), I decided to include in my app the best webview possible: [the latest version of Google Chromium](https://crosswalk-project.org/).

But.. no success again.

---

**1, 2 and 3 combined**

The result: no... success.

Comment: You need to test for the HTML5 API. Your device may not have the correct webview library. Your alternative is to use the [crosswalk (webview) plugin](http://phonegap.com/blog/2015/06/16/phonegap-updated-on-build/) see bottom of post for how to use plugin.

Comment: On ios the input type file works fine and show the gallery or camera option, on android it doesn't work. You have to use the camera plugin

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 Thanks for the note, but I used Crosswalk plugin.

Comment: @jcesarmobile so nothing we can do without cordova camera ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a solution, without the need for Cordova/PhoneGap's Camera API.

For reasons that are beyond my knowledge, the webkit used in [CocoonJS](http://cocoon.io/) (named WebView+) is far more optimized and adjusted to HTML5 apps than phonegap's Crossswalk (please, I am not related to Cocoon).

I discarded completely my Phonegap config.xml settings and tried Cocoon builder. I used the solution #1 (the capture attribute in file input) and added these plugins, via Cocoon:

```
<cocoon:plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera"/>
<cocoon:plugin name="cordova-plugin-media-capture"/>
<cocoon:plugin name="cordova-plugin-media"/>
<cocoon:plugin name="cordova-plugin-file"/>
<cocoon:plugin name="cordova-plugin-device"/>
```

**It's important to note** that I just installed these plugins in order to obtain the wanted permissions, but I am not using them at all.

---

Probably, more experienced developers will have better solutions but, for now, this is the best way I found to solve this problem.

Comment: Legend! Was in the exact same position as yourself, tried all steps listed above.  Simply installing the plugins you listed in cordova was enough for me, although CocoonJS is worth a second look.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment, @trans1t !