# Access to camera on android using HTML not working

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, camera

we want to upload an image to our server using a Cordova client. Currently we are using a  which works great on iOS (opens a dialog where you can choose between image from gallery or camera). 
However, on android, it behaves differently, as it won't give the option to choose an image from the camera but will open the gallery straight up. It works on mobile browser but not through webview.

My question is this: why does the android not give me the option to choose between gallery and camera like iOS does, and if possible, how can I make it behave this way?

- note: We want to avoid using the Camera API in Cordova and use pure HTML for this.

Any solutions are welcome,
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35090461/using-camera-on-phonegap-app-only-with-html-input-without-camera-api

Comment: Can you show some code so someone can reproduce your issue?